# C# syntax understanding Oracle Connection Project

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I have to modify a Visual Studio 2010 C# project that works with Oracle, looking at some code I've found a function that returns a `List<>` with values loaded from a database stored procedure (cursor)

```
while (myIDataReader.Read())
{
    // OK
    myTable.myStringField = myIDataReader["TableStringField"].ToString();
    // ¿?
    myTable.myIntField =
    Convert.ToInt32((myIDataReader["TableIntField"] == DBNull.Value) ? null : myIDataReader["myTableField"]);
}
```

Everything's ok, just want to know, what conditions are given when assign `myTable.myIntField`, I know this column is nullable, but I don't get the syntax, if someone can explain I'll be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about this line?

```
myTable.myIntField =
Convert.ToInt32((myIDataReader["TableIntField"] == DBNull.Value) ? null : myIDataReader["myTableField"]);
```

If you break that statement apart, you have a type of conditional, often called the Ternary operator, [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
conditional ? if_true_do_this : if_false_do_this
```

It is really just a different syntax for:

```
if(conditional) {
    if_true_do_this;
} else {
    if_false_do_this
}
```

After that, it simply passes the result to `Convert.ToInt32()` to turn it from a `string` into an `int`.

So that line of code is just a more concise version of this:

```
if(myIDataReader["TableIntField"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    myTable.myIntField = Convert.ToInt32(null);
}
else
{
    myTable.myIntField = Convert.ToInt32(myIDataReader["myTableField"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax above works correctly and it means:

`TableIntField` could contains a database null.
This is expressed in NET via the [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) object and its Value field.

The code checks if the `TableIntField` contains the `DBNull.Value` via C# [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).
If the checks result in a true condition, a null is used as argument for Convert.ToInt32 and this,  according to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx),  result in a zero value assigned to myTable.myIntField.